# Invalid Argument with $_SESSION

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I'm testing out a small wordpress plugin I created for a client of mine and I have an issue on one of the computers I am testing on. I'm thinking it may not be saving the `$_SESSION` data...

It gives me an invalid argument for this `foreach()`

```
foreach ($_SESSION['page-1'] as $key => $value) {
    $score += $value * 2;
}
```

The odd thing about this is it works on both my desktop and my laptop, but not the 2nd desktop I'm testing on.

Basically what that `foreach()` does is get `$_SESSION` information from a previous page and then just translates it into a new variable for the current page.

Comment: Session_start() at the beginning of your script?

Comment: Yup. And like I said it works properly in multiple browsers and on multiple computers, just not 1 browser on 1 computer. It's strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your session variable `$_SESSION['page-1']` is not an array.
Just check for it before entering the foreach:

```
if (is_array($_SESSION['page-1'])) {
    foreach (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It either one of the following:

- You are not setting `$_SESSION['page-1']` as an array anywhere, but just as any other type.
- You forgot to start the session (with `session_start`) or you have a logic error in your script that cause `$_SESSION['page-1']` not to be set or to be unset at some point therefore leading to `foreach (NULL as ...)` triggering the error.

Remember: you have to start the session with:

```
session_start();
```

**everytime** you try to get or set a session variable. Otherwise you are just setting or retrieving an undefined variable.

Comment: That will get rid of the error message - but is the error message the enemy, or is it the error itself?

Comment: Yes that would get rid of the error message, but without that array data the script cannot continue.

Comment: Whats interesting is it does it on FireFox on the 2nd desktop, but not Internet Explorer? Could it be a browser setting disabling $_SESSIONS? I don't think it would be as other sites function properly...

Comment: @CoryNickerson, rather than disabling session it could disable cookies. Check for the `enable cookies` option. It must be that. (Sessions ID are stored as cookies).

Comment: DO you know where in the browser I can check the cookie settings?

Comment: THanks for your help Jueecy. I checked the browser, cookies were enabled as it was using default settings. Out of curiosity I cleared the cache for all history. It now works? What could cause this! Could the cookie have been conflicting with another cookie or another type of data the browser stores?